# How to get folder name in a repository in azure pipeline using bash?

Tags: bash, azure-devops, environment-variables, azure-pipelines

How to get folder name in a repository in azure pipeline using bash?
We have repository named abcd, under that repo we have folder1, folder2, how do we get that folder name and print in echo using bash. and can we use this variable in release pipeline, is that possible??

Comment: What you have tried so far? You can clone the repository locally and get the directory structure from local git repo directory

Comment: @krishna Not get your latest information, is Krzysztof Madej's workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 2):

To get directories in a given folder you may use this:

```yaml
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Get all directories of $(Build.SourcesDirectory) and assign to variable
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |

      $arr = Get-ChildItem '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)' | 
       Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | 
       Foreach-Object {$_.Name}

      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=arr;]$arr"

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: List all directories from variable
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |

      echo '$(arr)'
```