# Azure Pipeline set of tasks for each folder in root DIR of repo

Tags: bash, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a requirement in which

```
for each top level folder in the azure repo:
    print(foldername)
    execute an entire set of tasks or stages of tasks around pylint and other various stuff
```

I am just trying to save the folder names across the whole pipeline but having issue retrieving and saving them...

**my yaml file**

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include: [ '*' ]
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: Gather_Folders
  displayName: "Gather Folders"
  jobs:
    - job: "get_folder_names"
      displayName: "Query Repo for folders"
      steps:
        - bash: echo $MODEL_NAMES
          env:
            MODEL_NAMES: $(ls -d -- */)
```

**output**

```
Generating script.
Script contents:
echo $MODEL_NAMES
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/jflsakjfldskjf.sh
$(ls -d -- */)
Finishing: Bash
```

I checked and the variable just takes the literal command itself instead of its output.. what am I missing here?

I was hoping to inject the folder names into a pipeline variable.. then somehow execute for each folder... a stage or set of stages in parallel

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, Krzysztof Madej gave an answer in this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61590030/11508192). To get directories in a given folder you can use the following script:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Get all directories of $(Build.SourcesDirectory) and assign to variable
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |

      $arr = Get-ChildItem '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)' | 
       Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | 
       Foreach-Object {$_.Name}

      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=arr;]$arr"

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: List all directories from variable
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo '$(arr)'
```

Comment: I was aware of that solution but I am not going to use powershell, if at all possible..